# sed matching greedier than expected

Tags: bash, curl, sed

I'm trying to write a line in Bash that gets the Content-Type (without encoding) of a given URL. Thisi s what I have so far:

```
curl -Is http://www.google.com | sed -nr 's/^Content-Type: ([^;]*)/\1/Ip'
```

However, this is still printing `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` and not just `text/html`. Shouldn't `([^;]*)` stop the match after the first semicolon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
curl -Is http://www.google.com | sed -nr 's/^Content-Type: ([^;]*).*/\1/Ip'
```

Basically add a `.*` after the matching group so that the part after text/html; will not be output.

Comment: Is the EOL anchor really necessary if using .* at the end of the line?

Comment: Reading the question, I made the same mistake the OP did, but now I think that I understand the answer.  It is true that the pattern matches either way, but the answerer's pattern explicitly matches the entire line.  Therefore, the answerer's pattern explicitly *replaces* the entire line.  The OP's pattern doesn't do the latter.